# 'useEffect' not run only once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

---

**Thanks everyone, especially Mr.Drew Reese. If you are newbie as me, see his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69474833/14745811).**

---

I don't know why but when I console log state **data** if I use **useEffect**, it always rerender although state **generalInfo** not change :/ so someone can help me to fix it and explain my wrong?

I want the result which is the **data** will be updated when **generalInfo** changes.

Thanks so much!

This is my **useEffect**

======================== **Problem** in here:

```
  const {onGetGeneralInfo, generalInfo} = props;
  const [data, setData] = useState(generalInfo);

  useEffect(() => {
    onGetGeneralInfo();
    setData(generalInfo);
  }, [generalInfo]);
```

======================== **fix:**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    onGetGeneralInfo();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(generalInfo);
  }, [generalInfo, setData]);
```

this is **mapStateToProps**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const {general} = state;
  return {
    generalInfo: general.generalInfo,
  };
};
```

this is **mapDispatchToProps**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onGetGeneralInfo: bindActionCreators(getGeneralInfo, dispatch),
  };
};
```

this is **reducer**

```
case GET_GENERAL_INFO_SUCCESS: {
        const {payload} = action;
        return {
          ...state,
          generalInfo: payload,
        };
      }
```

this is **action**

```
export function getGeneralInfo(data) {
  return {
    type: GET_GENERAL_INFO,
    payload: data,
  };
}
export function getGeneralInfoSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: GET_GENERAL_INFO_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
  };
}
export function getGeneralInfoFail(data) {
  return {
    type: GET_GENERAL_INFO_FAIL,
    payload: data,
  };
}
```

and this is **saga**

```
export function* getGeneralInfoSaga() {
  try {
    const tokenKey = yield AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenKey');
    const userId = yield AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
    const params = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenKey}`,
      },
    };

    const response = yield call(
      fetch,
      `${API_GET_GENERAL_INFO}?id=${userId}`,
      params,
    );
    const body = yield call([response, response.json]);

    if (response.status === 200) {
      yield put(getGeneralInfoSuccess(body));
    } else {
      yield put(getGeneralInfoFail());
      throw new Error(response);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getGeneralInfoFail());
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: The dispatch of `onGetGeneralInfo()` seems to update the `generalInfo` state which triggers the `useEffect` callback, which dispatches of `onGetGeneralInfo()`... do you see the issue? When and how often do you want the effect to run?

Comment: useEffect will always be called for first render and after that it will be called again if any value specified in deps array changes.

Comment: If you want to call useEffect specifically when generalInfo changes, you can create a ref and initially set it's value to false. In the useEffect check if ref.current is false, if it false then set it to true (this is the first render) and then do whatever you want to do in else condition.

Comment: @DrewReese I see. But I still haven't found a way to solve it. I just want to get the data for the 1st time open screen, and update state when I put to edit data.

Comment: Is the data already in your redux state when the component mounts? If not then it won't be available until it is fetched in the `useEffect`. It is also anti-pattern to store passed state/props into local component state.

Comment: @aditya81070 tks you.  I will try your way.

Comment: @DrewReese not yet. the initial state in rudux and state in component is an empty array. so I want to **GET** data from API. and I push it to redux's state. then I useState it. I want to use useEffect because I want to update state when I **PUT** the data and update local state after update. and my code is not good so as you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the initial state in redux and state in component is an empty array.
> so I want to GET data from API. and I push it to redux's state. then I
> useState it. I want to use useEffect because I want to update state
> when I PUT the data and update local state after update.

Ok, so I've gathered that you want fetch the data when the component mounts, and then store the fetched data into local state when it is populated. For this you will want to separate out the concerns into individual effect hooks. One to dispatch the data fetch once when the component mounts, the other to "listen" for changes to the redux state to update the local state. *Note that it is generally considered anti-pattern to store passed props in local state.*

```
const {onGetGeneralInfo, generalInfo} = props;
const [data, setData] = useState(generalInfo);

// fetch data on mount
useEffect(() => {
  onGetGeneralInfo();
}, []);

// Update local state when `generalInfo` updates.
useEffect(() => {
  setData(generalInfo);
}, [generalInfo, setData]);
```

Comment: Tks u so much. I understanded.

Comment: Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

in your `useEfect` you are setting `generalInfo` and it causes change in the dependency array of `useEffect`. So, it runs over and over:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onGetGeneralInfo();
    setData(generalInfo);
  }, [generalInfo]);
```

try this instead:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onGetGeneralInfo();
    setData(generalInfo); // or try to remove it if it is unnecessary based on below question.
  }, []);
```

However, I don't understand why you have used `setData(generalInfo);` in `useEffect` when you have set it before. does it change in `onGetGeneralInfo();` function?

Comment: tks for your answer. but if I remove `generalInfo` in [], the `data` is not update and it still a empty array although I log the `state` in **mapStateToProps** the `general` updated

Comment: I am not sure about your application! do you want to check if `generalInfo` has been changed then run `onGetGeneralInfo`? if yes, so you don't need `setData(generalInfo);` inside the `useEffect` anymore and keep your dependency array unchanged. If NO, so why you have put it inside the dependency array?

Comment: tks u. I got my problem

Comment: great, if my answer helped you I would be grateful if you upvote it

Comment: :v sorry but i have enough reputation to vote.
and my problem is in mr Drew Reese's answer.
Thanks you one more time. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

Yow hook has or uses things that are not listed in the dependencies list

```
useEffect(() => {
    onGetGeneralInfo();
    setData(generalInfo);
  }, [   onGetGeneralInfo, setData,   generalInfo]);
```

Also let's remember that useEffect is call before the component mounts  and after it mounts, so if you add a log it will be printed

Comment: hmmm. I got my problem in mr Drew Reese 's answer.
Tks u so much.
Have a nice day